# Fulltext search on innodb with two JOINs

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, innodb

I'm trying to do a fulltext search with innodb on mysql 5.6 and I added a `FULLTEXT KEY` on `submissions.title, submissions.description`. Here is my `show create table` for `submissions`:

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `submissions` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('tip','request') NOT NULL,
  `thumbnail` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `removed` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`,`description`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and when I run the following query:

```
SELECT s.*, MATCH (s.title, s.description) AGAINST ('whatever'), u.username, SUM( sv.up ) helpfulVotes
FROM submissions s
INNER JOIN users u ON s.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN submissions_votes sv ON s.id = sv.submission_id
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY s.created DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I get `#1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes` as an error.

Does this mean that I need to add a fulltext to the other fields that I'm joining? Doesn't really make sense since I'm not searching against any of those fields...

EDIT: Was doing the query on my prod machine which has an older mysql version, plus my query was wrong.

Correct query:

```
 SELECT s . * , u.username, SUM( sv.up ) helpfulVotes
 FROM submissions s
 INNER JOIN users u ON s.user_id = u.id
 LEFT JOIN submissions_votes sv ON s.id = sv.submission_id
 WHERE MATCH (
 s.title, s.description
 )
 AGAINST (
 'whatever'
 )
 LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

Comment: Try it without the join?

Answer (score 0):

I think Fulltext search is ISAM only.

Comment: @drewlander . . . And wouldn't the error show up on the `create table` execution rather than on the query execution?

Comment: Yeah... mihai is correct.  Since last I knew it has been added for innodb.  now you have me curious...

Comment: @GodronLinoff, edited: 

I installed 5.5 and it does error on create table if you run it from MySQL workbench.  


innodb_version 5.5.34
protocol_version 10
slave_type_conversions 
version 5.5.34

bob, can you paste the results from this command: 
show variables like "%version%";

Comment: `+-------------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value               |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.13              |
| protocol_version        | 10                  |
| slave_type_conversions  |                     |
| version                 | 5.6.13              |
| version_comment         | Source distribution |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64              |
| version_compile_os      | osx10.8             |
+-------------------------+---------------------+`